# difference between http and jdbc:mysql protocol?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, protocols

If http implicitly means port 80 and jdbc:mysql: implicitly means port 3306, why do we have to specify port 3306 in a mysql address, yet not need to specify port 80 in a http address?

Comment: You don't need to specify the port if it is 3306. Why do you think it is required? (also, this is specific to a driver implementation, and has nothing to do with how things work for HTTP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MySQL Connector/J docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html#hosts):

> If port is not specified, the corresponding default is used.

It's up to each provider of a protocol parser to implement defaults if they want.